# Pandas: Cumulative sum from 2 columns with conditions

Tags: python, pandas

Suppose i have two farms, A and B. Each week there are different animals there. How can i get the cumulative number of the animal that is currently at each farm?

```
+---+-----+--------+-----+--------+
|   |  A  | Farm_A |  B  | Farm_B |
+---+-----+--------+-----+--------+
| 0 | dog |   1    | cat |   1    |
| 1 | cat |   0    | dog |   1    |
| 2 | cat |   0    | dog |   1    |
| 3 | cat |   1    | dog |   0    |
| 4 | dog |   1    | dog |   1    |
| 5 | dog |   0    | dog |   0    |
| 6 | dog |   1    | cat |   1    |
+---+-----+--------+-----+--------+
```

With groupby i can get the cumsum from each farm:

```
df['A cumsum Farm_A'] = df.groupby(['A'])['Farm_A'].cumsum()
df['B cumsum Farm_B'] = df.groupby(['B'])['Farm_B'].cumsum()

+---+-----+--------+-----+--------+-----------------+-----------------+
|   |  A  | Farm_A |  B  | Farm_B | A cumsum Farm_A | B cumsum Farm_B |
+---+-----+--------+-----+--------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 0 | dog |   1    | cat |   1    |        1        |        1        |
| 1 | cat |   0    | dog |   1    |        0        |        1        |
| 2 | cat |   0    | dog |   1    |        0        |        2        |
| 3 | cat |   1    | dog |   0    |        1        |        2        |
| 4 | dog |   1    | dog |   1    |        2        |        3        |
| 5 | dog |   0    | dog |   0    |        2        |        3        |
| 6 | dog |   1    | cat |   1    |        3        |        2        |
+---+-----+--------+-----+--------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

My problem is, how can i get the cumulative sum of animals from both farm A and B for each row?

For example row 3: 
The animal at Farm A is cat, then i want the sum of cats from both farm A and B from row 0, 1, 2, 3 =  2 cats.

At line 3 again, the animal at farm B is dog, then i want the total number of dogs from both farm from row 0, 1, 2, 3 = 3

This is what i want to achieve:

```
+---+-----+--------+-----+--------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|   |  A  | Farm_A |  B  | Farm_B | A cumsum Farm_A | B cumsum Farm_B | A at both farms | B at both farms |
+---+-----+--------+-----+--------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
| 0 | dog |   1    | cat |   1    |        1        |        1        |        1        |        1        |
| 1 | cat |   0    | dog |   1    |        0        |        1        |        1        |        2        |
| 2 | cat |   0    | dog |   1    |        0        |        2        |        1        |        3        |
| 3 | cat |   1    | dog |   0    |        1        |        2        |        2        |        3        |
| 4 | dog |   1    | dog |   1    |        2        |        3        |        4        |        5        |
| 5 | dog |   0    | dog |   0    |        2        |        3        |        5        |        5        |
| 6 | dog |   1    | cat |   1    |        3        |        2        |        6        |        3        |
+---+-----+--------+-----+--------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: I think there's a typo in your output for A at both for row 4. There are 5 dogs [A0, B1, B2, A4, B4]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last two columns can be created working with dummies. This allows you to create a `cumsum` per animal type across farms, which you can then `lookup` to get the appropriate value for each row.

```
import pandas as pd

res = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['A', 'B'])
# Animals only count if dummy & exists, so need to multiply.
res = pd.concat([res.filter(like='A_').multiply(res.Farm_A, axis=0),
                 res.filter(like='B_').multiply(res.Farm_B, axis=0)],
                axis=1)
# Cumsum per animal
res = res.groupby(res.columns.str.split('_').str[1], axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.sum(1).cumsum())
#   cat  dog
#0    1    1
#1    1    2
#2    1    3
#3    2    3
#4    2    5
#5    2    5
#6    3    6

# Lookup
df['A at both'] = res.lookup(df.index, df.A)
df['B at both'] = res.lookup(df.index, df.B)
```

---

#### Output

```
     A  Farm_A    B  Farm_B  A at both  B at both
0  dog       1  cat       1          1          1
1  cat       0  dog       1          1          2
2  cat       0  dog       1          1          3
3  cat       1  dog       0          2          3
4  dog       1  dog       1          5          5
5  dog       0  dog       0          5          5
6  dog       1  cat       1          6          3
```

Comment: I realised a new problem though. I also have a column for the year (stored as integer, for example '2017'). I want to start counting from zero again every new year. Any thoughts about that?

Comment: I worked around the year-problem by spliting the dataframe. Big thanks for the help above! :)

Comment: @Gordon Ah sorry I couldn't get back to you sooner, yes that would have been my advice for something like this where the number of splits isn't terribly large.